# How to split Prisma Model into separate file?

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, orm, prisma

I'm learning Prisma ORM from video tutorials and official docs. They are explain and write All model code in one file called `schema.prisma`. It's ok but, when application grow it became messy. So, how should I separate my Model definition into separate file?

Answer (score 10):

At this point in time Prisma doesn't support file segmentation. I can recommend 3 solutions though.

**Option 1: Prismix**

[Prismix](https://github.com/jamiepine/prismix) utilizes models and enums to create relations across files for your Prisma schema via a prismix configuration file.

```
{
  "mixers": [
    {
        "input": [
            "base.prisma",
            "./modules/auth/auth.prisma", 
            "./modules/posts/posts.prisma",
        ],
        "output": "prisma/schema.prisma"
    }
  ]
}
```

Placing this inside of a prismix.config.json file which will define how you'd like to merge your Prisma segmentations.

**Option 2: Schemix**

[Schemix](https://github.com/ridafkih/schemix) Utilizes Typescript configurations to handle schema segmenting.

For example:

```
// _schema.ts
import { createSchema } from "schemix";

export const PrismaSchema = createSchema({
  datasource: {
    provider: "postgresql",
    url: {
      env: "DATABASE_URL"
    },
  },
  generator: {
    provider: "prisma-client-js",
  },
});

export const UserModel = PrismaSchema.createModel("User");

import "./models/User.model";

PrismaSchema.export("./", "schema");
```

Inside of User.model

```
// models/User.model.ts

import { UserModel, PostModel, PostTypeEnum } from "../_schema";

UserModel
  .string("id", { id: true, default: { uuid: true } })
  .int("registrantNumber", { default: { autoincrement: true } })
  .boolean("isBanned", { default: false })
  .relation("posts", PostModel, { list: true })
  .raw('@@map("service_user")');
```

This will then generate your prisma/schema.prisma containing your full schema. I used only one database as an example (taken from documentation) but you should get the point.

**Option 3:** Cat -> Generate

Segmenting your schema into chunk part filenames and run:

```
cat *.part.prisma > schema.prisma
yarn prisma generate
```

Most of these if not all of them are referenced here in the currently Open issue regarding support for Prisma schema file segmentation https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2377

Answer (score 4):

This is not yet possible with Prisma. See this outstanding issue for possible workarounds https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2377.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

[prisma-import](https://github.com/ajmnz/prisma-import) is a relatively recent solution and, in my opinion, the best one. It has its own branch of the Prisma VSCode extension for a nice workflow, using import statements analogous to JS imports.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge all schemas into one before generating

`yarn add -g glob`

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "prisma-concat": "npx ts-node prisma/concat-schemas.ts && npx prisma format",
  "generate": "yarn prisma-concat && npx prisma generate",
}
```

```
// connect-db.prisma

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

```js
// prisma/concat-schemas.ts

import { appendFile, readFile, writeFile } from 'fs/promises'
import { glob } from 'glob'

const start = async () => {
  const schemaFile = 'prisma/schema.prisma'
  const connectFile = 'prisma/connect-db.prisma'
  const models = await glob('src/**/*.prisma')
  const files = [connectFile, ...models]

  await writeFile(schemaFile, '')

  await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (path) => {
      const content = await readFile(path)
      return appendFile(schemaFile, content.toString())
    }),
  )
}
start()
```

And run `yarn generate`

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called Prismix that allows you to write as many schema files as you'd like, here you go the [link](https://github.com/jamiepine/prismix)